# Vuex3 mutation doesn't work when committed the then() of a promise

Tags: javascript, vuex

I have a vuex store that looks like this:

```
new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        foo: "initial value"
    },
    mutations: {
        update_foo (state, payload) {
            state.foo = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        update (context) {
            context.commit("update_foo", "bar");
            APIwrapper("api url to get data")
                .then(response => context.commit("update_foo", "not bar"))
                .catch(e => console.error(e));
        }
    }
}
```

When I `store.dispatch('update')` from my vue instance, it faithfully mutates foo to be "bar". Once the APIwrapper promise does it's thing, the update_foo mutation is called, dumping out the store shows that state.foo equals "not bar", but that change is not reflected in my template.

I am *not* super wild about re-writing my api wrapper object. Is there any particular reason why this doesn't work and is there a work around?

EDIT: Here's the rest of my setup.

Template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <i :foo="foo" v-html="foo"></i>
</div>
```

And my vue instance looks like:

```
new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#selector',
    template: template,
    beforeCreate: function () {
        store.dispatch('update');
    },
    computed: {
        foo: () => store.state.foo,
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you post your template/component?

Comment: Sure thing. I did several iterations on the template syntax trying to get it to bind correctly. This is just my latest version.

Comment: Have you tried to log the response to see does it actually get the correct data?

Comment: Yep. I've dumped out everything in the then(); the response, the store, the specific key in the state. Everything is set correctly, but the mutation inside the promise doesn't get reflected in the template. I can change it outside the promise and the markup adjusts exactly as it should. Inside the promise does not get propagated.

Comment: I test your code and it was actually changed to "not bar" on my side. But I did not do everything inside Vue instance. I created single file test.vue and worked with vuex from that.

https://imgur.com/a/7Uk2I

Comment: Grr. My codepen is also not recreating the problem, either. I guess there must be something in my APIwrapper that is somehow fouling the scope or otherwise breaking the binding. Thanks for everyone's time. https://codepen.io/upchurch/pen/MrLZvW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some brainstorming help, I managed to root out the problem. I had two Vue instances on the page that, through shared base classes, were using a common variable to store the instance. So, the one was overwriting the other. The instantaneous mutations worked because the instance still existed, but by the time the API responded, the instance had been overwritten and the update was failing.

Sloppy on my part. Thanks for everyone's time.